getDescribe().fields.getMap() doesn't return fields removed from Managed Package, but still present
There were fields removed from one of our Managed Packages that were still being used in a Test Sandbox. These fields are visible, editable, available on the Page layout etc. However new Apex code is failing because to my surprise, when running ..getDescribe().fields.getMap() on the object, these fields are not showing up in the Map. The code was checking if field names entered were correct, but it now seems that getMap() is not returning all fields, making it impossible to do such a check perfectly.
Does anyone know if this a known issue / on purpose?

Do you miss the Namespace of the object in the getDescribe method? For example mypackage__ObjectName__c.getDescribe()....?

No, it's complete with namespace. The namespace for the custom object is also the same as the namespace for the custom fields. The fields show up everywhere except for in the getMap(). Using them with dynamic SOQL in Apex without the check worked fine. It's just that now they are skipped because they're not found in the Map.
